# Auto Toggle 2G/3G When Screen On/Off on Android

Tags: android, android-networking, telephonymanager

I want to write an android app. When screen off, this app should set for mobile data only 2G. When screen on, it should set for mobile data both(2G/3G).

To do so, I should change mobile data type programmatically. How can I do this ?

I checked network type and I got the correct result.

this rom does it but I want to know how to do this : http://www.gregsbits.com/2012/04/saving-your-battery-through-aokp-rom.html

onCreate()

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(manager.getNetworkType()==TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE){
            tx.setText("Edge"); 

            int enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                    "preferred_network_mode", -1);
            Log.d("MYAPP", "2G only enabled: " + enabled);

        }
        else{
            tx.setText("3G");
            cm.setNetworkPreference(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE); //I'm trying
            cm.startUsingNetworkFeature(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE, "Deneme"); //I'm trying

        }
```

Comment: The ROM can do it because the application wich toggles 2g/3g is a system app. This is NOT possible on normal apps.

Answer (score 0):

The third party access to the 2G/3G/LTE toggle setting is disabled by google starting from Android 5.0 Lollipop.

So without Rooting the device which runs the OS android 5.0 and above whatever the requirement you stated may not be possible to implement!